# Sempre apresenta um erro quando tento usar a expressão mysqli

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

sei que a expressão `mysql` foi descontinuada, sendo assim, estou tentando usar a expressão `mysqli`, porém sempre que tento mostra-me na tela um erro de sintaxe!
exemplo:

```
$buscaDados = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM usuario");
```

Gera este erro:

> Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters

Como corrijo esse erro?

Answer (score 6):

É necessario passar dois agumentos quando o 'modo procedural' é usado. O primeiro é a conexão e o segundo a consulta.

[mysqli_query](https://www.php.net/mysqli_query)

> mixed mysqli_query ( mysqli $link , string $query [, int $resultmode =
> MYSQLI_STORE_RESULT ] )

Seu código deve ficar assim:

```
$buscaDados = mysqli_query($conexao, "SELECT * FROM usuario");
```

Answer (score 4):

Veja a assinatura do método no [manual](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli.query.php)

> mixed mysqli_query (mysqli $link, string $query [, int $resultmode = MYSQLI_STORE_RESULT ])

Isso quer dizer que você precisa passar a conexão (que é um valor do tipo *resource*) como primeiro parâmetro, e a query como segundo.

Na versão orientada a objeto é possível usar um parâmetro apenas:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $mysqli->connect_error);
    exit();
}

$buscaDados = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM usuario");
```